# Why is MySQL rounding division of 2 decimal to an unexcepted value?

Tags: mysql, rounding

I have a table with the following data:

Area VARCHAR(50),
Revenue DECIMAL(20,2),
Expense DECIMAL(20,2),
PercentBilled DECIMAL(6,2)

These values were imported from a spreadsheet and the percent billed is not precise enough. It's rounded to 2 decimal places. I can calculate it by taking Revenue / Expense, but I'm not getting the value I'm expecting.

Select * from  would return 'Counter', -1822.90, 2749.63, 0.66

-1822.90 / 2749.63 = -0.6629619.... which the absolute value would round to 66.3%, which is the precision I need.

So why then, when I run the following query:
Select Area, (Revenue / Expense) AS calcPercentBilled, PercentBilled from

I get: 'Counter, -1822.90, 2749.63, **1.000000**, 0.66 ?

My guess is it's something funky with MySQL and types, but I can't figure out what's happening. Why is MySQL rounding the division of 2 decimal numbers in a query to 1.000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the data type you have specified for PercentBilled.
`DECIMAL(6,2)` means store the value with 6 digits with 2 of them after the decimal point. So to increase the precision of the value stored you'll need to change the type of the column, perhaps to `DECIMAL(9,6)`. This would allow the value in your example to be stored as "0.662962" (i.e. six decimal places).

Note that simply updating the type of the column will not magic up the missing precision unless you re-import your data from source. Simply changing the data type without re-loading the data will change it to "0.660000".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I know what you're saying, but I am trying to calculate the other digits past .66 in a select query because the spreadsheet will only ever have 2 digits of precision. I still don't know why the select query is being rounded to 1.00000 instead of 0.6629619.

Comment: well in MySQL 5.7 if I do the same thing I get "0.662962".
i.e. 
create table foo(x decimal(20,2), y decimal(20,2));
insert into foo values (-1822.90, 2749.63);
select (x/y) as z from foo;

gives z = 0.662912

what version of MySQL and what client tool are you using?

Comment: One other thing - you have a "1.00000" appearing (i.e. +1), yet one of your numbers is negative - so the answer should also be negative. Are you sure you haven't divided a column by itself by accident?
as "select (x/x) as z from foo" in the above example gives z =1.000000

Comment: Welp, I'm an ID710T. It wasn't the same column but it was the incorrect column. I noticed after I expanded the query to multiple Areas and there were other values that also pointed to this.

Comment: happy to help. 
Often just asking a question makes you read everything again.